# `#namespace > .mixin()` vs. `.namespace.mixin()`

Tags: syntax, namespaces, less

All the Less documentation and tutorials use `#namespace > .mixin()` syntax when it takes into namespaces. However I find myself to be more comfortable with `.namespace.mixin()` syntax, i.e.:

```
.namespace() {
    .mixin() {
        foo: bar;
    }
}

#usage {.namespace.mixin()}
```

Am I missing something? Is there ANY difference between these two variants (in particular, the way a mixins/variables affect scope and vice versa)? Or is it just some kind of a historically rooted tradition?

---

Obviously `.namespace > .mixin`, `.namespace.mixin` and `.namespace .mixin` are different beasts when they are used as selectors. But things seem to be dissimilar when it goes to mixin invoke/expansion. I cannot craft an example where:

```
"#usage {#namespace > .mixing}"
"#usage {#namespace.mixing}"
"#usage {#namespace .mixing}"
```

etc. produce non equal output, assuming `.mixin` is defined as parametric ruleset. Same for `.namespace`.
E.g.:

```
/* A */
#namespace {
    .mixin1() {
        foo1: bar;
        .mixin1() {
            foo2: bar;
        }
    }

    .someruleset {
        foo3: bar;
        .mixin1 {
            foo4: bar;
        }
    }
}

/* 1 */
#u1 {#namespace > .mixin1()}
/* 2 */
#u2 {#namespace .mixin1()}
/* 3 */
#u3 {#namespace.mixin1}
/* 4 */
#u4 {#namespace .mixin1}
/* 5 */
#u5 {#namespace.mixin1.mixin1()}
/* 6 */
#u6 {#namespace.someruleset.mixin1()}

/* B */
.namespace {
    .mixin1() {
        foo1: bar;
        .mixin1() {
            foo2: bar;
        }
    }

    .someruleset {
        foo3: bar;
        .mixin1 {
            foo4: bar;
        }
    }
}

/* 1 */
#u1 {.namespace > .mixin1()}
/* 2 */
#u2 {.namespace .mixin1()}
/* 3 */
#u3 {.namespace.mixin1}
/* 4 */
#u4 {.namespace .mixin1}
/* 5 */
#u5 {#namespace.mixin1.mixin1()}
/* 6 */
#u6 {#namespace.someruleset.mixin1()}
```

All 1-6 results seems to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was not intended initially and was more like overlooked. However, after all these years it turned out to be more useful than harmful and there's no reason and intention to change this behavior in foreseeable future (or ever). Thus by now (2020) this behavior is more or less "official".

In other words:

- Mixins and namepsaces may be declared by either `id` or `class`
  element identifier (i.e. using `#` or `.` prefix)
- For namespaced/nested mixin invoke/call statement, any combinator part (like `>`, `+` or whitespace) of the selector is ignored and affects nothing. E.g.:

```
#namespace.mixin();
#namespace .mixin();
#namespace > .mixin();
#namespace>    .mixin(); 
// etc.
```

All of above statements are are identical and match exactly the same mixin(s).

Same for `.namespace #mixin` and other combinations.

Answer (score 3):

`.namespace.mixin` refers to an element with both classes while `.namespace .mixin` will find all .mixins in .namespace, or was that just a typo?

Comment: You're right, ".namespace > .mixin", ".namespace.mixin" and ".namespace .mixin" are different beasts when they are used as selectors. But things seem to be dissimilar when it goes to mixin invoke/expansion.
.. my answer is too long for a comment so I append it to my orginal question - see above ...